# prog.c:42:27: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having trouble with pointers which I just started learning about so any help with my one error would be awesome. It's a guessing game where the user has to guess a random number between 1 and 1000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Function Prototypes
int usein (int ran_num);
int usein2 ();
int again;

int main (void)
{
    //Declare Variables And Pointer
    int again = 1;
    int *ranum;
    int ranum1, invinp;

    //Random Number
    srand(time(0));

    //To Repeat
    do
    {
        ranum1 = rand() % 1001;
        ranum = ranum1;

        invinp = usein (ranum);

        if (invinp == 1)
        {
            puts ("Cya");
            again = 0;
        }
        else
            again = *again();
```

This right above.

```
    }
    while (again ==1);

    return 0;
}

/*************************function usein*************************/
int usein (int ran_num)
{
    //User Input
    int usenum;
    int reval = 0;

    printf ("Enter a guess.\n");
    scanf ("%i", &usenum);

    //Invalid Input
    while (usenum > 1000 || (usenum < 0 && usenum != -1))
    {
        printf ("It doesn't work like that... Try a number from 1 to 1000.\n");
        scanf ("%i", &usenum);
    }

    if (usenum == -1)
        reval = 1;
    else
    {
        if (usenum > *rand)
        {
            puts ("Too high. Go down.");
            usenum = usein2 ();
            if (usenum == -1)
                reval = 1;
        }
        else if (usenum < *rand)
        {
            puts ("Too low. Go up.");
            usenum = usein2 ();
            if (usenum == -1)
                reval = 1;
        }
        else if (usenum = *rand)
            puts ("Congrats. You guessed correctly!");

    }
    return reval;
}

/*************************function usein2*************************/
int usein2(int ran_num)
{
    //User Input
    int usenum;

    printf ("Enter a guess.");
    scanf ("%i", &usenum);

    while (usenum > 1000 || usenum < 0)
    {
        printf ("Try again dude.");
        scanf ("%i", &usenum);
    }

    return usenum;
}

/*************************function again*************************/
int again1()
{
    char question;

    printf ("You wanna go again?\n");
    getchar ();
    question = getchar ();

    while (question != 'Y' && question != 'y' && question != 'n' && question != 'N')
    {
        printf ("Try again.\n");
        getchar ();
        question = getchar ();
    }
}
```

Comment: `again` is not a function, what are you trying to do with `again()`? Did you mean `again1()`?

Comment: `int again;` is not a function prototype (near the top). Also, there's no return in `int again1()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int again;` declares an integer, not a function. The function you actually define down below is named `again1`. When you try to call `again()` from main, it complains that you're trying to call something that isn't a function, which is true because `again` is an `int`. Call `again1` instead (or better yet, give it a decent name). Also remove the `*` from `*again()`, it makes no sense as there's nothing to dereference. `again1` also doesn't actually *return* an `int`, so that would be the next thing to fix. You have several other problems in your code that will prevent it from working, most notably all the uses of `*rand` — I don't know what you're hoping for that to do, but it won't do it.